# How to keep HTML Form inputs horizontal and centered, while moving the label above the box?

Tags: html, css

I am trying to get my CSS to accomplish what you see in the picture

[The HTML Form Goal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nyFqr.png)

I want to move the labels Minute, Seconds & Tens to the top of the form inputs. While keeping the form centered horizontally.

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  padding-bottom: 8px;
  font-size: 22px;
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

input {
  display: inline-block;
  padding:10px 20px;
  font-size: 18px;
  letter-spacing:2px;
}

#formSection {
  padding-top: 30px;
}

#button {
  color:#fff;
  background:#3399cc;
  padding:20px 40px;
  margin-top: 20px;
  text-decoration:none;
  letter-spacing:2px;
  text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <div id="formSection">
    <label for="minIn">Minutes</label>
    <input type="number" value="20" name="mins" id="minIn"> 
    <label for="secsIn">seconds</label>
    <input type="number" value="10" name="secs" id="secsIn"> 
    <label for="tensIn">Tens</label> 
    <input type="number" value="5" name="tens" id="tensIn">
  </div> 
  <input type="submit" value="submit" id="button" onclick="submitMins();return false">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit @A. Meshu. It's much clearer now.

Comment: No problem. Next time do it yourself with the snippet icon (:

Comment: For sure! I understand it now :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put the label/inputs into their own individual `div` containers with a `display: inline-block` then also added a `display: block` to your label/input elements. FYI your beginning CSS is missing it's class. I just assumed it was `minIn`

```css
.minIn {
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
padding-bottom: 8px;
font-size: 22px;
font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
}

.container {
    display: inline-block;
}

input {
padding:10px 20px;
font-size: 18px;
letter-spacing:2px;
}

label, input {
    display: block;
}

#formSection {
padding-top: 30px;
}

#button {
color:#fff;
background:#3399cc;
padding:20px 40px;
margin-top: 20px;
text-decoration:none;
letter-spacing:2px;
text-transform:uppercase;
}
```

```html
    <form>
        <!-- <div id="formSection"> -->
            <div class="container">
                <label class="minIn">Minutes</label>
                <input type="number" value="20" name="mins" id="minIn">
            </div>
        
            <div class="container">
                <label for="secsIn">seconds</label>
                <input type="number" value="10" name="secs" id="secsIn">
            </div>
    
            <div class="container">
                <label for="tensIn">Tens</label>
                <input type="number" value="5" name="tens" id="tensIn">
            </div>
        <!-- </div>  -->
    
        <input type="submit" value="submit" id="button" onclick="submitMins();return false">
    </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

I changed your markup and minimized `CSS` in order to show you the basic concept:

```css
form {text-align: center; width: 100%;} /* center the form content */
#formSection { /* put each label on center */
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: center;
}
#formSection input {display: block; } /* place inputs as new line under label's text */
```

```html
<form>
    <div id="formSection">
        <label for="minIn">Minutes
            <input type="number" value="20" name="mins" id="minIn"> 
        </label>
        <label for="secsIn">seconds
            <input type="number" value="10" name="secs" id="secsIn"> 
        </label>
        <label for="tensIn">Tens
            <input type="number" value="5" name="tens" id="tensIn">
        </label> 
    </div> 
    <input type="submit" value="submit" id="button" onclick="submitMins();return false">
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how you can do that:

```css
        input {
            padding: 10px 20px;
            font-size: 18px;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
        }

        .field {
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .field label {
            display: block;
        }

        #formSection {
            padding-top: 30px;
        }

        #button {
            color: #fff;
            background: #3399cc;
            padding: 20px 40px;
            margin-top: 20px;
            text-decoration: none;
            letter-spacing: 2px;
            text-transform: uppercase;

        }
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>

<body>
    <form>
        <div id="formSection">
            <div class="field">
                <label for="minIn">Minutes</label>
                <input type="number" value="20" name="mins" id="minIn">
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="secsIn">seconds</label>
                <input type="number" value="10" name="secs" id="secsIn">
            </div>
            <div class="field">
                <label for="tensIn">Tens</label>
                <input type="number" value="5" name="tens" id="tensIn">
            </div>
        </div>

        <input type="submit" value="submit" id="button" onclick="submitMins();return false">
    </form>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.